# qwt приближения/удаления и перемещения по графику под управлением тачскрина

Tags: c++, qt

Есть в qwt два класса  QwtPlotMagnifier и QwtPlotPanner. Как можно задействовать scroll bar или Slider для передачи данных о приближение/удаление или перемещение графика на плоскости?

Comment: QwtPlotMagnifier и QwtPlotPanner тут не при чём, просто устанавливайте диапазон с помощью, setAxisScale, как вам нужно

Comment: Не совсем понял. Вот вывел я график. Хочу растянуть его. И мне снова его перерисовывать, изменяя приделы с помощью setAxisScale?

Comment: а по любому график надо перерисовывать, просто классы QwtPlotMagnifier и QwtPlotPanner они не для прямого программирования, они сами обрабатывают ввод и перерисовывают

Comment: А как можно передавать данные с scroll bar или Slider в QwtPlotMagnifier и QwtPlotPanner ?

Comment: но для чего же это надо передавать в  QwtPlotMagnifier и QwtPlotPanner если они для этого не предназначены?

Comment: Не совсем понял. Но спрошу, как можно растягивать график, перемещать средствами тачскрина? Тачскрин резистивный.